# How much loan was given to Lord Venkateshwara by Kuber?

Tags: vishnu, venkateshwara, tirupati

In the story of Lord Venkateshwara, He had taken loan from Kuber in order to marry Padmavati. Kubera gave the loan on the condition that Vishnu cannot return to Vaikuntha (heavenly abode) without paying off the debt. Lord Vishnu resides at Tirumala as Tirupati Venkateswara without returning to Vaikuntha until the payment is made. To help him repay his debt, devotees offer him wealth and in return Lord Vishnu fulfills their prayers. Through a facebook post, I came to know that daily contributions in Tirupati Temple is approx INR 8 crore. I want to know how much was the loan given by Kuber to Lord Venkateshwara and looking at the contributions whether the loan is still pending and if yes then how much is still pending?

Comment: The loan was for 1.4 million Ramamudra coins.  My understanding is that donations to the Tirupati Hundi are only applied to the interest on the loan, not the principal, and the principal of the loan is only due at the end of the Kali Yuga.  Perhaps Kubera set a  really high interest rate.

Comment: Also, I don't think Vishnu's decision to stay in Tirupati has anything to do with Kubera's loan.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I read this from wikipedia page on Lord Venkateshwara at url: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venkateswara. Can you please confirm this story with what you're telling and put that as an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The loan given to Lord Venkateshwara by Kubera was 1.4 million in Ramamudra Coins.

The loan was given under the condition if the debtor makes an executory note. The promissory note was dictated by Brahma and Lord Venkateshwara himself wrote it.

> This, the 7th day of the bright-fortnight of the month of Vysakha in Kaliyuga, The debtor is Srinivasa, ‘the creditor is Dhaneswara. Purpose : marriage of the loanee. **Amount of Loan fourteen lakhs in Ramamudra coins**. The loanee should repay it with interest in one thousand years after the loanee’s marriage.” Brahma and Siva attested as witnesses. The scribe was the loanee himself. After accepting the promissory note, Kubera paid the amount in cash. Srinivasa requested Kubera to purchase and get all the articles and material required for the marriage Viz., clothes, pulses, rice, wheat the auspicious Mangalya thread etc.,

Above passage is an excerpt from *Sri Venkatachala its Glory* by Chalapati Rao. This book contains the Sthala Purana (temple legends taken from various Puranas). This book is co published by Tirumala Tirupati Devasthanams (TTD).

The condition for giving the credit is if the debtor makes the executory note by himself. Lord Venkateshwara did that. Lord Brahma and Lord Shiva signed as witnesses. This loan has nothing to do with Lord's stay on Venkatachala hills. This episode of Venkateshwara taking loan for marriage [is just his leela](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/18539/5212).  He was present there even before that. The marriage happened in this Kaliyuga and there are stories in various Puranas which involve different deities (e.g Kumara Swami. This is from Vamana Purana) and sages worshipping him on the Venkatachala .

The duration period is in Deva years because it is signed in the presence of God. That could take the period approximately upto the end of this Kali Yuga. So, it is believed that what ever he is paying back (from Hundi) is counted as interest rather than the principle. So, the pending amount cannot be determined.

Comment: How much is that in today's value?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Thanks for ur reply and once again I saw I got no notification for the same. Its only when I checked this question I get to know that it's being answered already. Seems some problem with SE.